# What are some good-practices to get an open-source project to have contributors?

Tags: open-source

I am involved in a project which is meant to eventually become open-source and have a code contributor community.  Is there any "right" way of doing this and what should/can I expect?

Thanks

Comment: Great question, but probably belongs on programmers.SE.

Comment: Actually I have no idea why they made a separate overflow site for programmers.  I thought that was the point of stackoverflow in the first place

Comment: The questions on Stack Overflow pertain to programming problems and algorithms.  The questions on Programmers pertain to subjective questions on software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommand using [Github](https://github.com/) or [Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/GettingStarted) (subversion/mercurial), and of course use social media network to promote the project helps too.

Answer (score 3):

There's a pretty good book on this topic, [Producing Open Source Software](http://producingoss.com/) by Karl Fogel, which is available for free online or in dead tree form if you prefer to read it that way. It would be hard to expand much on it in a single answer. Every project will, of course, be different, so I'd recommend reading that book, and then asking more specific questions about your particular project; answers will depend on the language and platform you use, how active an open source community there already is in your area, what your business model is, and many other factors.

Answer (score 1):

You can start something like this - http://wxwidgets.org/develop/